# ModelBuilder Iterate Layers not functioning

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

Iterate layers cycles through in other variables except Output layer.

Here you can see the cycle of Name output is working properly, but the output layer is always passed as the first one in the workspace.[image]

Here are my iterate layer parameters[image]

This was working a few days ago, nothing has been changed.

Things I've tried:

- ArcGIS update
- Removing all functions, starting clean in a new model,
- setting preconditions to assure rastertoASCII runs last
- Iterating layers in a different workspace with different and fewer
  rasters (also properly worked before). Results in same mind boggling
  bug.

Comment: As a side note, if your upgrade to arcpro 3.0 you can turn off the grouping behaviour that was introduced in 2.8. so you don't have to deal with the nutty layer names you have.

Answer (score 0):

The tool before this names the layers (variable name: name of file). The layer names have `%YearIOP%.tif` as the variable name. I renamed this to `YYIOP` to remove the `%s`. This fixed the issue with the iterate layer tool.